# button bar not filling the parent in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have a LinearLayout with three buttons but those are not filling the whole screen.
Hard to find the right answer. 
With GridLayout it works fine but I have to have support for APIs less then 21.

[image]

XML file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/barMenu">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/topBarFilterText"
        android:id="@+id/buttonTopBarFilter"
        android:onClick="onClickTopBarFilter"
        android:background="#BABAFF"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/topBarCityText"
        android:id="@+id/buttonTopBarCity"
        android:onClick="onClickTopBarCity"
        android:background="#9999ff"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/topBarMyOffersText"
        android:id="@+id/buttonTopBarMyOffers"
        android:onClick="onClickTopBarMyOffers"
        android:background="#9999ff"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you setting width to wrap_content and still expecting to fill the whole view ?

Comment: I`am new to Android development that's why I asked this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use layout_weight

`

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/topBarFilterText"
    android:id="@+id/buttonTopBarFilter"
    android:onClick="onClickTopBarFilter"
    android:background="#BABAFF"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/topBarCityText"
    android:id="@+id/buttonTopBarCity"
    android:onClick="onClickTopBarCity"
    android:background="#9999ff"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/topBarMyOffersText"
    android:id="@+id/buttonTopBarMyOffers"
    android:onClick="onClickTopBarMyOffers"
    android:background="#9999ff"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
```

`

Comment: Perfect! But do you know how to set the button text on one line? The last button text push the "erbjudande" text under "Mina" text.

Comment: Found it... android:singleLine="true"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill the horizontal screen equally, then you should check the documentation for the xml attribute android:weight.
For each button you need to add the following:

```
<Button
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_width="0dp" 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/barMenu"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonTopBarFilter"
    android:layout:weight="1"        
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#BABAFF"
    android:onClick="onClickTopBarFilter"
    android:text="string/topBarFilterText"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonTopBarCity"
    android:layout:weight="1"        
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#9999ff"
    android:onClick="onClickTopBarCity"
    android:text="string/topBarCityText"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="13sp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonTopBarMyOffers"
    android:layout:weight="1"        
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#9999ff"
    android:onClick="onClickTopBarMyOffers"
    android:text="string/topBarMyOffersText"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="13sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```